# iPhone Chrome browser is not allowed to make calls directly

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome

While trying to make some calls through the google search in my iPhone 11, Chrome warned me that the site is repeatedly trying to open another app.
I accidentally hit Block and now it is not allowing me to make any call through the google search call button.

[image: Pressing the call button has no effect now]

Pressing the call button has no effect now. How do I revert this?
I tried to find a configuration/setting but could not find any.

iPhone 11 running iOS 13.6.
Chrome for iOS  v79.0.3945.73

Comment: I just tried and didn't get a "Block" type message, just an confirmation to dial the number. Did you check in the Chrome section of Settings whether something can be enabled there?

Comment: You have to repeatedly try to call. Like 10 times in a short period.